# Setting Individual Folders To a Different Sorting Method? & Icon Size

Tags: macbook-pro, finder, photos, folders, sort

How do you set each folder on the MacBook to a different sorting method?
It's driving me crazy: I've watched videos, googled & nothing, no answers.

Say I have 3 Folders on the desktop. I want to make each of the 3 folders icon view for photos. I then want to set each one to a different sorting method. 1st by name the 2nd by name the 3rd by size etc etc.

As of right now, Every time I change the sorting method to Kind, for example, it makes every single folder on my computer sort by kind.

Also Is there a way to make each folder a different icon Size? & save as well. I only use icon view. I have 100's of folders so I can't just save as default. I can't even keep the folders the same size.

I know this is like 5 questions but its a nightmare. I see open folder in icon view & I can check it & it has view in icon view as well? Why not the other 3 options?

Those are my questions. I really appreciate you guys so much if you could help me. I'm turning to the pros for this, because no one seems to know.

Comment: Sorting and View is a property of the Window, not the Folder it contains.

Comment: could you please explain in layman's terms my friend? I know the folder is what im working with. but im not sure what you mean by window.

Comment: A window is the fundamental 'rectangle' that displays information on computers. A Document in Pages, or a webpage in Safari, is displayedin a Window. A folder is a hierarchical container in the file system. It has an icon that looks like -- a cardboard folder. The Finder (the application where you browse files) displays files and folders within windows.

Comment: Could you add some screenshots to your question, showing the problem?